# What is the typical manner in which official/stable Helm charts are maintained?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I’m finding that numerous popular projects have little or no Kubernetes/Helm related work in their main or even container-based repos and it seems quite fragmented.

I belong to other dev communities which have stable charts and I’m wondering where issues/PRs and valuable discussions commonly take place for most of these projects.

Considering the main chart repo seems reserved for Helm specific development, where do you all find most of the work taking place for individual charts?

Comment: There's not really an answer here, it depends on the project. Develop in the main stable/incubator repos until you find it impacts or doesn't suit your workflow. If it does impact bring the charts into your own repo and export your chart on local release out to stable. If you run into issues with their release process, move to your own chart repo.

Comment: Agree with @Matt, just to add, that if you keep your own Helm Chart repo, you can consider adding it to Helm Hub (https://hub.helm.sh/) for the sake of discoverability.

Answer (score 2):

Stable helm charts are [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable). Incubator charts are [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator).

Some projects like istio carry their [own helm charts](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/kubernetes/helm).

[This link](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#support-channels) has information about issues/PRs and discussions about helm charts in Slack channels.

Chartmuseum is also a repository of helm charts:

- https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum
- https://chartmuseum.com